# Reasons for failing to send an email through App Script when specific text is added

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to send an email through app script when a specific cell changes in Google Sheets.

**The app script runs, but the email does not arrive when the sheet is updated according to the condition.**

**[Desired result]**

: If the text ‘구독만료’ appears in column H, I want to send some information about that customer via email.

I used the if function to display the text ‘구독만료’ in column H when the data in column E passes today.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIigh.png)

**[Question]**

1. When I run the app script, I can see that the email is being sent. Is there a problem with the code just by looking at it?
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdUbz.png)

---

```
 function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(""전체 고객목록"");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var startRow = 2; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow, 21);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var customerNumber = Number(rowData[0]);
    var customerId = rowData[1];
    var customerName = rowData[2];
    var expirationDate = rowData[6];
    var expirationStatus = rowData[7];
    var thenumberofunpaid = rowData[12];
    if (expirationStatus == '구독만료') {
      var searchRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, 21).getValues();
      for (var j = 0; j < searchRange.length; j++) {
        if(searchRange[j][7] == '구독만료'){
          var message_value = "일련번호: " + searchRange[j][0] + "\n" + 
                              "주문자ID: " + searchRange[j][1] + "\n" + 
                              "주문자명: " + searchRange[j][2] + "\n" + 
                              "마지막 결제일: " + Utilities.formatDate(searchRange[j][6], "GMT+9", "yyyy-MM-dd") + "\n" + 
                              "미납 횟수: " + searchRange[j][12] + "\n" ;
          var subject = "[커피] 구독 만료 고객 확인 요청드립니다.";
          var message = "안녕하세요. \n\n공유드리는 고객님은 오늘부로 구독이 만료 되었습니다.\n확인 후 정기배송 해지 처리 부탁드립니다.\n링크 연결:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HhLko_7-5zGJEuiMYDd6tb0ttAONxPcKjE0pcXiHFWI/edit#gid=1652156064 \n\n" + message_value;
          MailApp.sendEmail("ch__@gmail.com", subject, message, {cc: "___94@gmail.com"});
            }
          }
           break;
        }
      }
}
```

---

2. It works when executed, but when ‘구독만료’ appears in column H, no email is sent. I want to know the cause and solution.

How and where should I modify the app script to make it works?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please pose code into question.  But if you using an onEdit then be aware that it only fires on user edits.

Comment: **`DO NOT post images of code... - copy or type the text into the question.`** - Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: 1) Are you familiar with [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)? 2) Have you created an installable `onEdit` (or even `onChange`) trigger for `sendEmails`?